# Find instances of values across multiple arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to calculate retention rates of customers in my platform. I want to see how many customers came to the platform 4 times in 4 weeks, 3 times in 4 weeks, twice in 4 weeks, and once in 4 weeks.

The first and last data points are easy to get, but I can't figure out how to calculate the middle two.

I have array's of customer ID's that were active per week. For example:

```
week_one = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
week_two = [1, 2, 3, 6]
week_three = [1, 2, 7]
week_four = [1, 2, 3, 8]
```

The result I'm trying to get is:

customers who used the platform 4 times in 4 weeks: `[1]`

customers who used the platform 3 times in 4 weeks: `[2, 3]`

customers who used the platform 2 times in 4 weeks: `[7]`

customers who used the platform 1 time in 4 weeks: `[4, 5, 6, 8]`

...

With these values, I can then say:

1 customer used the platform 4 weeks in a row, 2 customers used the platform 3 times in the 4 week period, 1 customer used the platform 2 times in the 4 week period, and 4 customers used the platform 1 time in the four week period.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for "in a row" or "in a 4 week period" because 3 is 2 weeks "in a row" but 3 times in a "4 week period" so the question is a bit unclear and the implementations would vary depending on the desire.

Comment: Hey, I updated the question to keep the wording consistent and be more clear.

Comment: Assuming that you don't want someone doing the homework for you, you should also make clear at which point you got stuck. For example, you could describe the algorithm you have in mind, and explain which part of your algorithm you can't translate into Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can obtain the desired result as follows:

```
arr = [*week_one, *week_two, *week_three, *week_four]
```

```
arr.tally.then {|h| h.keys.group_by { |k| h[k] } }
  #=> {4=>[1], 3=>[3,2], 1=>[4,5,6,8], 2=[7]}
```

The intermediate result is

```
arr.tally
  #=> {1=>4, 3=>3, 4=>1, 5=>1, 7=>2, 2=>3, 6=>1, 8=>1}
```

See [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally).

---

Another way to compute the desired hash is:

```
arr.tally.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| (h[v] ||= []) << k }
```

Comment: I always forget about `#tally`. As an aside `tally.then {|h| h.keys.group_by {|k| h[k] }}` is a bit more compact and equally as performant according to `fruity` plus now we can do ugly things like `tally.then{_1.keys.group_by(&_1.method(:[]))}` :)

Comment: We are grouping by number of occurrences as you have shown. So `tally` produces `{1=>4, 3=>3, 4=>1, 5=>1, 7=>2, 2=>3, 6=>1, 8=>1}` then we use `Object#then` (`#yield_self`) and we group the `keys` by the `values` as `h.keys.group_by {|k| h[k] }`

Comment: @engineersmnky, very nice, a definite improvement. I've edited my answer. Many thanks.

Comment: Nice @CarySwoveland, i wasn't aware of the `#tally` method. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this would be to join all the arrays into one bigger array

```rb
monthly_visits = week_one + week_two + week_three + week_four
visit_count = {}

# from array of unique values, count how many times each value occurs
monthly_visits.uniq.each do |visitor_id|
  visit_count[visitor_id] = monthly_visits.count(visitor_id)
end

visit_count

# Hash returns each visitor_id as key, and number of visits as the value
# => {1=>4, 3=>3, 4=>1, 5=>1, 7=>2, 2=>3, 6=>1, 8=>1}
```

Hope this is the solution for your problem.

Comment: I was thinking something very similar, except that per my understanding, the resulting hash should have 4 keys corresponding to the number of visits and the values should be arrays containing the corresponding visitor ids.

Comment: @engineersmnky sure, it can be done in more ways, fully functional way is a very cool way of doing it, but it's less readable in my opinion.